# Creating Japanese NER training model in OpenNLP?

Tags: opennlp, cjk, named-entity-recognition

I'm looking into creating training data for a Japanese NER.

Wondering if I need to pre-tokenize the training data or is there a way to specify a Tokenizer during model creation?

In the example below Japanese doesn't have any whitespace:

```
<START:person> Pierre Vinken <END> 61 years old will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29 .

<START:person> Pierre Vinken <END> は11月29日、非執行取締役として理事に就任する。
```

Will this work for training a model or do I need provide the training sentences tokenized?

Answer (score 1):

It was a little hard to find the documentation on this but OpenNLP expects the training data to be pre-tokenized, see [here](https://opennlp.apache.org/docs/1.5.3/manual/opennlp.html#tools.namefind.training.tool):

> The data can be converted to the OpenNLP name finder training format. Which is one sentence per line. Some other formats are available as well. The sentence must be tokenized and contain spans which mark the entities.

This could be also inferred from the english example you gave since there's a space before the final period. As a rule, CRF training data is usually pre-tokenized, as that makes evaluation across software packages easier.

Once the sentences are tokenized OpenNLP should work fine with Japanese, since it doesn't really care what the strings are.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.rondhuit.com/apache-opennlp-1-9-0-ja-ner.html

I found this link which could be useful for your purpose.There is a pretrained NRE for the Japanese language which you can download

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)